# What is the thickness of endothelial lining in blood vessels?

Tags: endothelium

In capillaries, endothelial lining is one cell thick. Is same the case with bigger blood vessels?

Comment: Related http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54562/3340

Answer (score 1):

I believe apart from natural fluctuations of cellular size, the size of squamous epithelial cells (the cells making up the endothelium of blood vessels) remains the same. Therefore, the thickness of the endothelium does not significantly change for any blood vessel.

Comment: This is correct. Just to add on, capillaries are walled by essentially *only* endothelium; larger vessels are thicker because they have other types of tissue: elastic laminae, media and adventitia that contain smooth muscle cells and connective tissue.